# Why there is a grey "bar" between my <img> and <div>

Tags: html, css, svg

There is a grey line between an `<img>` which display a SVG and a `<div>`. 
Here the screenshot and part of the code.
[image: Screenshot of the issue]

```css
.svg{
 width: 100%;
 height: auto; 
 display: block;
}

.title-container{
 // center the title into the container
 display: flex; 
 width: 100%;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: $white;
 padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="assets/oblique.svg" class="svg"/>
<div class="title-container">
 <a href="/" >Example</a>
</div>
```

#### What I've already tried

I've already tried to set margin, padding and border to 0px, it doesn't work.
I've already tried to set margin, padding or border to -1px, but it create an overflow.

[image: Screenshot of the 2nd issue]

Comment: Guessing that your SVG is being scaled. Sub-pixel rendering is making the edges of your SVG half opaque. I suppose you could try `margin-bottom: -1px` on your `.svg` element.

Comment: Also in your html it should be `class` and not `className`.

Comment: There is written className because it is from a react project. My fault, I should have changed with class

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: I've tried your code with my svg and I don't get your problem. Can you please edit your question and add the svg you have?

Comment: @Rob in react you must close every tag, even the <br> tag . As I've already said, I've done copy and paste from my code, my fault I should have changed all these stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to make a skew top on your div.
You may like another approach without SVG.
Using `border-image`:

```css
body {
  background: #15100e
}

.title-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  background-clip:padding-box;
  padding-top: 10px;
  border-top: solid 50px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent calc(50% - 1.5px), #fff 50%) 100% 0 0 0 / 50px 0 0 0
}
```

```html
<div class="title-container">
  <a href="/">Example</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just tried it, thanks for the suggestion but it gives me an overflow like in the 2nd screenshot which is in my question.

Comment: @bruhurb, I've updated my answer to be more pixel-perfect.

Comment: thanks a lot, but I found a shorter solution that fit perfectly, I'll put it in my question if you would like to read it

Comment: @bruhurb, You might post your solution as an answer.